# Is there an equivalent to $InitialDatabase when using ScriptUpdate?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

The EF migrations Update-Database command accepts the following parameters:
-Script -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase.
The script generated is idempotent as explained in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621

Is there an equivalent parameter when using the ScriptUpdate method of the MigratorScriptingDecorator class?

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with the same, but it turns out you just have to provide "0".

Example function:

```
    public static string CreateUpdateScript(DbMigrationsConfiguration config, string sourceMigration, string targetMigration)
    {
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);
        var scripter = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
        return scripter.ScriptUpdate(sourceMigration, targetMigration);
    }
```

Then call it like this:

```
    CreateUpdateScript(new Configuration(), sourceMigration: "0", targetMigration: null);
```